# Convert two dimensional JSON array to C# array

Tags: c#, arrays, json, stringify

I have a simple question

How can I desterilize a Json stringified two dimensional array to two dimensional array

I have this JSON string

{"1":" 1","2":" 1, 2, 3, 4","3":" 1","4":" 2","5":" 3","6":" 4, 1, 2, 3"}

I want to convert it to

[1][1]

[2][1,2,3,4]

[3][1,4]

[5][3]

[6][4,1,2,3]

Regards

Comment: Show us the code you've tried, and an error or issue that you have with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json is not an array. It is a dictionary where some values are like `4, 1, 2, 3`

```
{ 
  "1": " 1",
  "2": " 1, 2, 3, 4",
  "3": " 1",
  "4": " 2",
  "5": " 3",
  "6": " 4, 1, 2, 3"
}
```

Using [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/)

```
var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Using  JavaScriptSerializer

```
var dict = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

Comment: Thank you!, it worked …actually I was trying like 

var strArray  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject< string[,]>(json);